# what is this code means in handlebar.js {{{number this.col1}}}?

Tags: handlebars.js

`{{{number this.col1}}}` in this expression 'number' keyword i am not able to understood properly , this keyword truncating decimal values

```
{{#each dataObject.listArr}}
      <h5 class="card-title m-0">{{{number this.col1}}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text m-0 font-weight-bold {{this.color}} text-uppercase text-wrap" style="font-size:9px">{{this.col2}}</p>
    <hr class="my-3">
{{/each}}
```

Comment: number is helper (function that gets value from this.col1 and return some result to view). https://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html

Comment: but why it is truncating decimal part from values present in this.col1